# How to write rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am developing a website in wordpress and I am trying to write a simple rewrite rule (seems pretty simple with all these documentation).

I need to change `http://www.mysite.com/fitness/wp-content/themes/fitness/favorites.php` to `http://www.mysite.com/fitness/favorites`. ***fitness*** is my home directory.

I have tried the following patterns in my **.htaccess** file but they all throw 404 error:

```
1. RewriteRule ^favorites$ /fitness/wp-content/themes/fitness/favorites.php

2. RewriteRule ^/favorites/$ /fitness/wp-content/themes/fitness/favorites.php

3. RewriteRule ^favorite\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteRule . /fitness/wp-content/themes/fitness/favorites.php [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a static page template...

Comment: and how exactly to call that template?? what should be the href tag?

Comment: It would be sweet if you actually read the documentation... http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+page+template

Comment: okay I have searched and read all possible documents but coudln't figure out how to solve this. I know how to include a template into a page but I still don't know how to call it with an href tag

Comment: never mind. Did it with a simple page. So easy that was. I am kicking myself for not getting this before. Anyway thanks for your comment and for your -1 too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will simple redirect your old URL to the new one.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^fitness/wp-content/themes/fitness/favorites.php(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/fitness/favorites$1 [r=301,nc]
```